# Hadoop installation on ubuntu12.10

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am the beginner on Hadoop and want to do the final year project on hadoop. But the first problem is on installation. I read about cloudera but its just confusing. I want to install hadoop for multi node in ubuntu 12.10. Please any one can help me out!! also if you can link me to some nice hadoop tutorial then it will be best.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? There are dozens of tutorials available if you just search for it, we are not here to Google for you

Comment: I am not asking you to be a Google for me!! I am asking for a guide from you guys and i think this place is the best one for help!! If you dont think so, then please stop wasting your time around this question.

Comment: Why don't you try to install it first and ask here if you have issues? There is a guide for exactly what you are after here: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the Cloudera will be the easiest to install.
If you want to go with the Hadoop provided at Apache site then the Micheal Noll tutorial is the easiest one to follow.

To avoid networking issues I installed 3 VirtualBoxes on my Laptop and connected them together, Two as Datanode and one as NameNode. Worked for me.

But as said, try first and then let us know of errors you face.

Comment: But cloudera installation is possible for64 bit only.. and trying to get ubuntu 64 bit needs amd but i have intel!! so, i guess i need a little more help from you.. thank you (:

Comment: I can guide you on Oracle Virtual Box. I have never used the VMWare.


1. Download 64 bit version of Ubuntu. It will have amd in its name. Do not worry about that.

2. When you are installing OS on VirtualBox then do not choose Ubuntu. Scroll down and Ubuntu 64 bit will be listed. Choose that.

3. When you start the install then 50% chance is that it will succeed. 50% chance it that it will complain that virtualization is not enabled. Restart your PC. Keep pressing F1. So that you go into the BIOS Menu. Look around. There will be Virtualization variable. Enable it. 
And you are good to go. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've installed Hadoop 1 and 2 on my Ubuntu 12.10 without any issues, here's how I done it, hope it helps:

http://tuliodomingos.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/installing-apache-hadoop-in-ubuntu-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions ([1](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/), [2](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/)) to setup Hadoop on a single and multi node cluster. Note that the instructions are for an older releases of Ubuntu, but are applicable for the Ubuntu 12.10 also.

For those who are new to Hadoop, a VM ([1](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Demo+VMs), [2](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/), [3](http://www.mapr.com/products/download)) with Hadoop installed and configured can be downloaded.